# Monogame runs slightly below target fps

Tags: xna, monogame, frame-rate

I recently changed my game to run at 144 fps rather than the default 60 fps but it always stays at 143 fps. It's not a big deal since you can't tell the difference without an fps counting program but I'd still like to know why this happens and how to fix it. Here's my code.

```
protected override void Initialize()
    {
        TargetElapsedTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0 / 144.0f);

        IsFixedTimeStep = true;

        graphics.SynchronizeWithVerticalRetrace = false;

        base.Initialize();
    }
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure the reason, but I've found that Monogame will always render one frame less than you would expect. Try setting the TargetElapsedTime to 145 FPS

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After hours of tinkering with code I've found this to be the best combination of settings. I left VSync on but disabled "FixedTimeStep". The game now runs fairly consistently at 144fps unless it's on a standard monitor in which case it runs at 60fps. This means I'll have to change a few animations to be time based rather than frame based but I was thinking of doing that anyways.

```
protected override void Initialize()
    {
        TargetElapsedTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0 / 144.0f);

        IsFixedTimeStep = false;

        base.Initialize();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

After calling `Game.Update` and `Game.Draw`, MonoGame spends any excess time by calling the system sleep function (`Thread.Sleep()` to be exact). The sleep call has millisecond accuracy at best, and may be worse depending on various factors. The difference between 143 and 144 FPS is about 0.05 milliseconds per frame - way less than the system timer resolution.

As far as I know, there is little you can do (apart from trying to enable VSync on a 144 FPS display). The difference is really minimal and subject to measurement errors. I wouldn't bother trying to fix it.